# RegEx: How to capture a sub section

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider the following simple textual information:

```
info
  start
    date=20140521
    val=key1
    info="Just a string"
  end

  start
    date=20140521
    val=key2
    info="Another one"
  end
end
```

I would like to capture a section based on the value of the 'val' field using the RegEx.

For the sake of example, assume that I would like to get val=key1 section.

Following regular expression doesn't capture anything!

```
(start((?=val=key1)(.|\s))*?end)
```

However, if I use the following one, I can capture the section which has val=key2 (opposite of what I want)

```
(start((?!val=key1)(.|\s))*?end)
```

Here is the section captured in this case:

```
  start
    date=20140521
    val=key2
    info="Another one"
  end
```

Any easy way of doing this?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Should be language independent, but at the end I will use C#.

Comment: Regular expressions are not language independent in any way, shape or form. The regex dialect being used makes a vast difference in the way something is done.

Comment: @KenWhite vast? Disagree. some differences on what more advanced parts are supported, but most simple regex are universal

Comment: @Bohemian: "Vast" in regard to things like lookarounds; several dialects don't support positive lookaheads, for instance. "Vast" in that there are several dialects that are substantially different in syntax (Perl vs. JavaScript vs. C# vs. PCRE vs. Java). Dialect is relevant with regard to regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore sections other than those that have `val=1`, you could use the following here.

```
(?s)(start((?!val=\d+).)*val=1\b.*?end)
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bC8rA9)</kbd>

**UPDATE**:

- To answer the updated edit, you could use the following to capture those sections.

  ```
  (?s)(start((?!val=\w+).)*val=key1\b.*?end)
  ```

  Regular expression:

  ```
  (?s)           set flags for this block (with . matching \n)
  (              group and capture to \1:
   start         'start'
   (             group and capture to \2 (0 or more times)
   (?!           look ahead to see if there is not:
    val=         'val='
     \w+         word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
   )             end of look-ahead
   .             any character
   )*            end of \2 
   val=key1      'val=key1'
     \b          the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
   end           'end'
  )              end of \1
  ```

  <kbd>[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qA3sK6)</kbd>

Comment: +1 Very good answer. I should have made the values more generic instead of numeric though.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find what's between a `start\s+val=1` and `end`, you could use something simple like:

```
(?s)\bstart\s+val=1\b(.*?)\bend\b
```

Where you could replace the `val=1` with whatever pattern you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful in deed. However, I would like to capture from start to end, because there could be other fields between start and val=x.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have, which is not captured by the example input, is when there is a start/end block preceding the one you want, because a naive regex, even using reluctant quantifiers, will match on the first start before the target value.

The solution is to consume as much input as possible before the match:

```
.*(start.*?val=1\b.*?end)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/6K5FRgwAZ0), which has an extra block before the target, which is captured as group 1.

This regex, which must be used with the "dotall" flag, captures your target block as group 1. The ".*" at the front is the small but important part that consumes any blocks that may precede your target.

You could be more strict by putting word boundaries `\b` around the various parts,if needed. A word boundary is probably advised after the target number though, so input like `val=12` aren't accidentally matched.